# How can I match everything between 2 commas?

Tags: regex

I want to match basically any text that has a comma separated list of weekdays.

```
(?i)(every (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)[A-Za-z]{3,5}, .*+, 
(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)[A-Za-z]{3,5})
```

Above is what what I have and I want to make it match the following strings. I don't need help in the case that only 2 weekdays are supplied.

```
Every mon, tue, wednesday
Every wed, Saturday, Friday, sun.
```

Comment: Surely you'd be better off just matching any day that is either written abbreviated or in full? Like an `OR` on all 14 options? Also, what kind of person uses both abbreviated and full names for days of the week, in a comma-separated string? Switching up like that is surely a sign of madness :P

Comment: what `Every wed, Saturday, Friday, sun.` should match?

Comment: Are you using a programming language here (such as Java or JavaScript) ?

Comment: Well that's mostly just because I'm still pretty new to regex. At the end of the day I just want to match a comma separated list of weekdays of  varying lengths.

Comment: I'm using Tasker which I believe uses Javascript style regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might list the abbreviations and optionally match the full name by listing them using an alternation followed by a comma and a space.

Add that to a group and repeat that 0+ times. After that add the group without a comma to make sure you match at least a single day.

```
(?i)\bevery (?:(?:mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?|thu(?:rsday)?|fri(?:day)?|sat(?:urday)?|sun(?:day)?), )*(?:mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?|thu(?:rsday)?|fri(?:day)?|sat(?:urday)?|sun(?:day)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?i)\bevery` Case insensitive modifier
- `(?:` No capturing group

  - `(?:mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?|thu(?:rsday)?|fri(?:day)?|sat(?:urday)?|sun(?:day)?),`  Match any of the listed followed by a comma and space
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?|thu(?:rsday)?|fri(?:day)?|sat(?:urday)?|sun(?:day)?` Match any of the listed
- `)\b` Close non capturing group and add a word boundary to prevent being part of a larger word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IAMNVn/1)

To not match only multiple days, you could update the `*` [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) for the first non capturing groupe to for example `+` or `{2,}`.

Comment: How do I can I edit this to avoid matching "Every thursday"?

Comment: Do you mean not match `thursday` or `thu` at all? Then you could omit it from the pattern. Or do you mean that you can match every day, except not start with `Every thursday`

Comment: I mean to not match single days. I want to only match lists of days. I don't want to match the following: "every Monday", "every Tuesday",...

Comment: In that case you could add a quantifier like `+` or `{2}` etc instead of the current `*` See https://regex101.com/r/IAMNVn/2

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern: `(?<=,|^)[^,\n]+`

Explanation

`(?<=,|^)` - positive lookbehind: assert what preceeds is comma `,` or beginning of the string `^`

`[^,\n]+` - match one or more characters other than comma `,` or newline `\n`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CaxNCB/1)